# Как сделать respawn в Unity конкретного объекта в его изначальной точке спустя время?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Мой проект похож на популярную игру hole.io, локация заполнена разными объектами, которые я Изначально расставляю на сцене (в будущем это будет, допустим, город). И мой персонаж, подобно черной дыре, эти объекты съедает: **под землей** стоит плоскость, при столкновении с которой объект деактивируется и игроку засчитываются очки, после чего он растет.
Это я реализовал, но теперь встала, казалось бы, простая, но крайне непонятная задача: как сделать так, чтобы после съедения, объект появился **на изначальной точке** спустя время?
Я сделал это так: в момент уничтожения (или деактивации) объект клонируется (под землей) и далее сверху появляется его копия.
Код:

```
if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Plants")
{
    Yrot = Instantiate(collision.gameObject, collision.gameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject; //копируем объект
    Yrot.transform.position = new Vector3(collision.gameObject.transform.position.x, 1.25f, collision.gameObject.transform.position.z); //заставляем его появиться по Y выше, на земле
    // collision.gameObject.SetActive(false);  // деактивируем объект и его копию, чтобы потом активировать через время
}
```

Это фрагмент от проверки по тэгу.
В результате этого кода: после уничтожения оригинального объекта, моментально появляется его копия НО(!!!) по тем координатам, где был уничтожен оригинал. Т.е. , пока, допустим, дерево падало сквозь черную дыру, оно могло изменить свои  координаты от Начальных и далее копия дерева также заспавнится по ним же (новым).
Мне нужна какая-то конкретная привязка, но привязывать каждый объект (коих более 200 на карте) не рационально.
Была мысль по поводу того, чтобы спавнить объекты сразу же после уничтожения в состоянии деактивации, а спустя время их активировать, будто бы они только сейчас появились. Но не разобрался со счетчиками, пробовал через карутины. Как решается моя задача? По возможности подскажите кодом, ибо я только учусь, это моя первая игра. Спасибо!

Comment: Не знаю как у тебя это реализовано, но я бы сделал суперкласс зданий и добавил бы туда свойство с начальной позицией, которая у каждого здания переприсваивается в Start'е и после уничтожения запускал корутину у какого нибудь контроллера зданий, которая через определенное время спавнила объект в этой начальной позиции. ну а так не знаю как тебе помочь

Comment: Да, я думаю, что это отличное решение. Что-то вроде того я уже начал делать.
Но, столкнулся с новой проблемой - не получается то ли записать, то ли считать координаты всех объектов. 
Подскажите, как бы вы в Start() записали все координаты зданий? Чтобы потом они автоматически вытягивались и на них происходил спавн

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял тебе надо заново респавнить объект в его точке, **когда он первый раз загрузился**. Но, ты дал мало данных, скажи как ты взаимодействуешь с деревом или домом например. И как ты их собрался респавнить.

У меня есть идея по этому поводу. В моём варианте, тебе надо не уничтожать съеденный игроком объект, а например, скрывать его (для новичка пойдёт думаю). Затем тебе стоит на каждый объект повесить скрипт(с классом конечно), где будет переменная **Vector3 startPos** и **float timeDead**. При старте, например в Awake или Start, ты в переменную **startPos** записываешь координаты объекта.

```
startPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
```

Затем тебе нужна функция **Dead**, она вызывается когда объект съеден. В ней, в переменную **timeDead** ты записываешь время со старта игры плюс **время которое не будет появляться объект**(для этого может быть отдельная переменная для удобства), то есть:

```
timeDead = Time.time + 5;
```

Где 5 это то самое **время которое не будет появляться объект**.
И далее ты должен проверить, Time.time >= timeDead, если да(болше), то объект можно заново показать.

Вот пример функции смерти и проверки на разрешение на спавн(я пишу без IDE, так что сори если есть синтаксические ошибки):

```
public void Awake()
{
    // старт игры 
    startPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
}
public void Dead()
{
    // смерть
    timeDead = Time.time + 5f;
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
public void Update()
{
    if(Time.time >= timeDead)
    {
        // показать объект и переместить его в координаты startPos.
        gameObject.SetActive(true);
        transform.position = startPos;
    }
}
```

ну вроде всё сказал. Покавыряйся немного и получится шикарно. Если есть какие то вопросы - пожалуйста, спрашивай - я не мастер объяснять.